# Angular 2 move component to back (Change z position)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to make a responsive web app with a side menu that hide and shows via a button when the screen is small. However, I am finding that when the menu shows, it shows "behind" my main component (As shown in the images below). I am using angular 2 with with with some javascript/css from [responsive website code](http://www.cssscript.com/responsive-sidebar-navigation-with-javascript-and-css3/)

[image: Side menu hidden][image: side menu shown]

My main app.component.html looks like

```
<header class="header clearfix">
    <button type="button" id="toggleMenu" class="toggle_menu">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <h1>Timesheet</h1>
</header>

<nav class="vertical_nav">
    <ul id="js-menu" class="menu">

        <li class="menu--item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/a']" class="menu--link" title="a">
                <i class="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-user"></i>
                <span class="menu--label">a</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="menu--item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/b']" class="menu--link" title="b">
                <i class="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-briefcase"></i>
                <span class="menu--label">b</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="menu--item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/c']" class="menu--link" title="c">
                <i class="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-cog"></i>
                <span class="menu--label">c</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="menu--item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/d']" class="menu--link" title="d">
                <i class="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-database"></i>
                <span class="menu--label">d</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <li class="menu--item">
            <a [routerLink]="['/e-csv']" class="menu--link" title="e">
                <i class="menu--icon  fa fa-fw fa-globe"></i>
                <span class="menu--label">e</span>
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</nav>


<div class="wrapper">
    <section>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a CSS style, or do it inline.

**CSS**

```
nav.vertical_nav {
  z-index: 9;
}
```

**Inline**

```
<nav class="vertical_nav" style="z-index: 9;">
```

Comment: Simple. Effective!